# Transmission causes internet to stop working - log off required to make it work again

Tags: internet, transmission

After some time of downloading torrents via Transmission the internet connection stops working, causing both torrents and sites to not load. This only happens on my machine (meaning other computers/tablets/smartphones in the house can browse just fine) and internet comes back exactly after I log out.

What is a little strange , as well, is that network manager shows that i am connected - i can also access the router's page at the time I am "offline"

Using utorrent to download torrents from windows 7 doesn't cause the same problem - neither using transmission on another ubuntu system running in the same network

I am connected using wi-fi, if that matters at all

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same issue and it's incredibly frustrating.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and it's incredibly frustrating. It will successfully download at very high speeds for perhaps 30 sec, then wifi just breaks and requires a restart. I have tried limiting peers/connections, limiting upload/download, unchecking "Enable uTP for peer communication", adding a Blocklist, ensured that my forwarded port is open in the router. Note: this only seems to happen on popular torrents.

Answer (score 5):

I think you *might* be experiencing the same problem as the one discussed in [Transmission slows down internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16680/transmission-slows-down-internet-connection). This is my answer to that question:

> The problem, in your case, is probably
>   not the data rate but the number of
>   connections. Many internet gateways
>   can't handle **many connections at the
>   same time**.
>
> You can Limit your maximum amount of
>   simultaneous connections in the
>   Transmission preferences like so:
>
> [image: Preferences → Network → Maximum Peers per torrent]
>
> Try to keep these values very low at
>   first. 5/10 is a good starting point.
>   And increase them slowly as you find
>   it working.
>
> - Note: Especially new torrents can show this behaviour. If you wait until
>     there are enough seeders for a
>     torrent, it'll be slowing down your
>     browsing much less.
> - Note also: You shouldn't have to limit bandwidth. This is handled by
>     the TCP/IP stack, no problem, in
>     *most* cases. It tries to schedule packet delivery fairly.

I found that some routers just give up under the load of a badly seeded torrent when you use many connections.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i already have limited the connections to a lot less than the connections i have allowed in utorrent but i still have the same problem . I used to have 150 and 350 in the fields you show above for some years(and had no problem with it - download and upload maxed easily when i wanted it to without me having any connection problems) and now i have 15/35.

Comment: -1 since the original question specifically rules out router issues.  I happen to be having the same problem, but with deluge.  And I have ruled out the router as well (by using different devices).

Answer (score 2):

Actually I found that implementing a blocklist improved transmissions behavior extensively. I had the issue that when I would use transmission torrents and web would stop, and I would unplug the modem and replug it in to get internet again. I tried lowering connections and other things but it seems the block list was the best answer. I put this url under transmission->edit-> preferences->privacy->url http://www.bluetack.co.uk/config/level1.gz (Ihope it is ok to post that)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in Ubuntu 14.04 with Transmission 2.82.

I solved it disabling in Transmission preferences the option "Enable uTP for peer communication" (it's in the preferences' Network tab).

I documented it here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2287460