# Internet connection drops while using torrent

Tags: internet, connection, bittorrent

Every time I use a torrent client my internet connection falls for my computer, i installed the new drivers but it's still falling. I tried Plurge and Transmission. Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Does this makes any sense?? -> http://askubuntu.com/a/44277/179042

Comment: What 'new drivers'?

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP may be monitoring for torrenting on their client's modems, and shutting down their internet in an attempt to fight piracy.

One way to check if it's the computer or your modem is getting another device on the network and checking if that works while your computer isn't.

Comment: I tried on Windows and this situations didn't happen.

Comment: and i tried on Elementary and had the same issue

Comment: @ErickFlávioResende look for a log for Transmission or Plurge in `/var/log`, and then link it in your question.