# Bittorrent is very slow

Tags: bittorrent, deluge, qbittorrent

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and bittorrent download speed is very slow. I tried many torrent clients, opened ports but nothing works.

I don't know what information you'll need for this problem so tell me what to do and I'll post them.

Comment: check number of peers and seeders before download and best thing that take your torrents file from Reliable site and open port in your router for your torrent

Comment: I tried both of that. I followed this guide to find best torrents http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Good_torrent port is opened but download speed is still very slow. It's about 10-20kb

Answer (score 1):

sometimes some isp's will throttle your bittorrent traffic.  some isps can be tricked by forcing your bittorrent traffic to another port and encrypting it.

what i do is force encryption and use the openvpn port tcp/1194 for my communications.  this seems to work for some places.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the *number of concurrent connections* is too high for your home/office router to handle. Try setting a lower maximum number of connections (or number of "peers") in your BitTorrent application.

This is commonly the cause of a whole Internet connection being slower, but it also often causes BitTorrent downloads to be slow (sometimes even when the Internet connection, for other uses, is reasonably fast).

There are more details in the answers to this question (which is related but not a duplicate, as it's specifically about the effect of BitTorrent on *other* Internet activity):

- [Using a bittorrent client slows down internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16680/transmission-slows-down-internet-connection)

Try lowering the *total* number of connections to somewhere around 20. (That is, not for *each* torrent, but for *all torrents combined*.)

If that helps, you can adjust it further (both up and down) to see what gives you the best performance.

If this does not help you, then please provide more information:

1. A screenshot of at least one BitTorrent application downloading torrents. Since many torrents have small swarms and thus may be slow some of the time anyway, I recommend showing a popular torrent download. If you create screenshots showing your bittorrent application downloading *just* [an Ubuntu ISO torrent](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads), or something similar, that may be best.
2. Detailed information about your network and Internet connection, including whether or not you're on a LAN, what kind of internet connection you have, its speed (if you know), the name of your ISP, if it's a home, business, campus, or other connection, and any other information you think may be pertinent. Giving all this information would be best but partial information is far better than none.

(Hopefully, limiting the number of connections will just work though, and the problem will be solved. Hopefully.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the bandwidth that your bit-torrent client is allowed to use, to a value that is about 5% less (depends on connection speed) than you have available on your Internet Connection.

You could be experiencing a networking problem known as buffer bloat.

The idea is to prevent the buffers in your router from getting full.

Comment: How do you recommend determining connection speed?