# Transmission kills my connection (torrent)

Tags: 12.04, bittorrent, transmission

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transmission slows down internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16680/transmission-slows-down-internet-connection)

I have a simple one today, I've been using transmission for a couple months now and since the beginning I noticed that if I open transmission, NOTHING else works.. well, I'm talking about internet, not even typing google.com at browser.

I tried setting up the upload limit to 5kbps and download to 20kbps.. even so the connection doesn't work.

One particular fact is that it happens just on my pc, because I can use internet with my laptop without any problem connected to the same router!

Anybody else with the same problem? does anybody knows about a fix?